# Jupyter Notebook: Run a Notebook cell programmatically within a loop

Tags: javascript, python, jupyter-notebook, ipython, cell

i would like to `run a specific jupyter code cell` within a function. the only option i found to execute a cell is:

```
IPython.display.Javascript("Jupyter.notebook.execute_cells([4])")
```

This is working but as soon as i implement the code into a python function it isn't doing anything anymore:

```
if version_val == ():
        IPython.display.Javascript("Jupyter.notebook.execute_cells([4])")
```

this is the whole code i try to execute (each cell is marked in a new block): 
1:

```
import os
import ipywidgets as widgets
import IPython
from IPython.display import Javascript
import plotly as py
import plotly.graph_objs as go
```

2:

```
if os.path.exists("Test"):
    test_exists = True
else:
    test_exists = False
    print("Found no folder named 'Test'!")

if test_exists:
subfolder = os.listdir("Test")
```

3:

```
enter2 = widgets.Button(description = "Enter")
version_val = ()
def update_d(self):
    IPython.display.clear_output()
    global dt
    dt = dropdown_testcase.value
    global subsubfolder
    subsubfolder = os.listdir(r"Test\{}".format(dt))
    global dropdown_version
    dropdown_version = widgets.SelectMultiple(options=subsubfolder, description="Mark Both <br> for <br>Comparison")
    display(dropdown_version)
    enter2.on_click(start_all)
    display(enter2)

def start_all(self):
    global version_val
    version_val = dropdown_version.value
    if version_val == ():
        print("Choose your data !")
    if version_val == ('Files',):
        IPython.display.Javascript("Jupyter.notebook.execute_cells([3])")



if test_exists:
    dropdown_testcase = widgets.Dropdown(options=subfolder, description="Testcase")
    enter = widgets.Button(description = "Enter")
    enter.on_click(update_d)
    display(dropdown_testcase)
    display(enter)
```

4:

```
x = [0,1,2,3]
y = [0,1,2,3]

trace = [go.Scatter(x=x, y=y, mode="markers")]
fig = go.Figure(data=trace)

py.offline.iplot(fig)
```

And i need the plot to be executed in the last cell.

It needs you to create a Folder "Test" inside the Folder of the Notebook and a subfolder named whatever you like. And in that subfolder must be a subsubfolder named "Files".

Does anybody know how to solve this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you have a solution and want to share, you can always answer your own question. If it is useful, I will vote up as we usually do here.

Answer (score 0):

(My answer concerns the question how to `run a specific jupyter code cell`)
On Jupyter notebook, you can access content of a cell with `In[]` and `Out[]`. Here is a simple code to try:

Suppose the code cell [13] has some computation already done:

```
In [13]:   1+2+3+4+5
Out [13]:  15
```

Somewhere in the same notebook, you can access and run the code in that cell like this:

```
print("Result from execution the cells above:", eval(In[13]), Out[13])
```

You should get the result as

```
('Result from execution the cell above:', 15, 15)
```

Hope this is helpful.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but i think this doesn't solve my problem. Perhaps i didn't make it really clear:

I have a Notebook which automatically runs all cells after start. There are several plots in several cells.
At the beginning i have a few dropdown menus and the plotting should not start until the user has chosen data from the dropdown menu.

Comment: Still unclear to me for what you want. You need to supply some relevant code specific to the problem you face and the solution you expect.

Comment: Ok sorry, i just edited my post above with part of the code. In my case there are another 7 cells and each cell contains one or more plots. these plots should all be executed in a seperate cell but they should be initialized by the "start_all()" function. 

Any ideas?

Comment: @TimDoll Please edit your question, adding that specific requirements to the question. Also add relevant code that shows your best attempt.