# Jupyter Notebook (VS Code) - Create a for loop that runs a cell like a function. The cell is using the Cantera library

Tags: jupyter-notebook, cantera

I would like to create a for loop that evaluates multiple inputs for a Cantera Reactor network and gives me the results. The Cantera network runs as a for loop, evaluates a time period, and generates results in numpy arrays then updates those to dataframe. I tried making the Cantera Network For-loop a function, but for some reason it makes the run times exponentially worse. I've noticed this to be a common problem in the Cantera library for other issues.

I want to create a Results Loop that will take inputs and run the Cantera Network For-loop by referencing the cell. Is this feasible? Example code below:

(You shouldn't need to know the Cantera library to help, I just want to specify why using a normal function isn't working).

I've tried this answer but it didn't work:
[Jupyter Notebook: Run a Notebook cell programmatically within a loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53556791/jupyter-notebook-run-a-notebook-cell-programmatically-within-a-loop)

Cantera network setup

```
Reactor1 = cantera.Reactor()
Reactor2 = cantera.Reactor()
sim = cantera.ReactorNet([Reactor1, Reactor2)]
```

Cantera Network For Loop

```
    for i in range(n):
        sim.advance(i)
        network_array[i] = sim.thermo.P
```

Results For Loop

```
inputs = [1,10,100]
for x in range(3):
    Reactor1.property = inputs[x]
    RUN THE CANTERA NETWORK FOR LOOP CELL
    results_array[x] = sim.Property_I_Care_About
```